# pyarrow writting Parquet files keeps overriding existing data sets

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I'm trying to write to an existing Parquet file stored on the local filesystem. But when writing multiple times, the previous one gets overridden instead of added.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


def append_to_parquet_table(dataframe, filename):
    full_path = os.path.join('.', filename)
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dataframe)
    writer = pq.ParquetWriter(full_path, table.schema)
    writer.write_table(table=table)

def save(passed):
    data = {'number': [1234], 
            'verified': [passed], 
            'date': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    append_to_parquet_table(data_df, 'results.parquet')

save(True)
save(False)
```

Why is the first data set being "updated" instead of a new one written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to write to an existing Parquet file stored on the local filesystem.

This isn't supported by the file format. Parquet files are immutable after being written.

Comment: So I'd have to read the file in, concat the two tables in memory and then write them back to the filesystem?